# Run php artisan command in out of laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am writing an installer for laravel project.
but for some reason, I don't run this installer from laravel project.
I use PHP code. I want to use `php artisan migrate` on my installer and I know that  I can use this command `system("php artisan migrate")` but I don't want to use `system functions` on my installer. Is there any way to `artisan` command on PHP out of laravel?

Comment: You can execute Artisan commands programmatically but not sure you could use it for what you want to do: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: I know this but I am out of laravel project.

Comment: What do you mean by "out of laravel project"?

Comment: I believe they mean to say their installer is not using Laravel and they also do not wish to use system calls from PHP as part of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately artisan is baked into the Laravel Framework so your options are limited but you still have options.

1. Use the [Spatie laravel-migrate-fresh](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-migrate-fresh) package (be sure to read before use)

   - This would be suitable for a fresh install process
2. Use a shell script for your build

   - You can easily incorporate a shell script to run your migrations
3. Roll your own installer using Symfony's console

   - Vivek Kumar Bansal provides a [good article](https://vkbansal.me/blog/trying-eloquent-artisan-commands-outside-laravel/) on his Blog to do just this
4. Create a standalone installer using Laravel

   - This can contain your migrations and other commands (with input if you like)
5. Nuno Maduros [Laravel Zero](https://laravel-zero.com) could actually be perfect for you!

   - It has migrations built in

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's `exec()` function. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

`exec('php artisan migrate');`

Comment: How is this any different to running `system("php artisan migrate")` which the OP is trying to avoid?.